# NOTE TO SELF messages are not saved

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7

If I use the Google voice command :note to self, it works and saves the message "using Gmail"  but I can't find it when searching on a unique keyword in the Note :

- gmail
- Google Keep
- Google search

  - clicking on View My Notes link displayed after it saves the Note (it just opens Gmail)

Android version 7.0 on Samsung s7

Comment: Is your G mail and keep updated?

Comment: Also Google - I had read in Google forums that such problems were resolved by updating concerned apps, hence suggesting